# How to do asynchronous updates to HTML with Firebase

Tags: javascript, firebase, asynchronous

I'm currently working on a project that involves updating some of the HTML depending on whether or not Firebase finds a resource in the database.  Here is a snippet of the code:

```
for(var i = 0; i<collection.length; i++){
    //Get the player
    var player = collection[i];

    //Create a new table row
    var row = document.createElement("TR");
    row.id = player.Id;

    //Add the player profile pic
    var imgNode = document.createElement("TD");
    var img = document.createElement("IMG");
    var photo = "https://usatftw.files.wordpress.com/2014/10/nfl_logo_new2.jpg?w=1000&h=750";
    playerbase.orderByKey().equalTo(player.Id).on('child_added', function(snap){

        photo = snap.val();

    });

    img.setAttribute("src", photo);
    img.setAttribute("width", "55px");
    img.setAttribute("height", "55px");
    imgNode.appendChild(img);
    imgNode.className = "player-photo";
    row.appendChild(imgNode);

    ... //Some more td is added below
```

The problem is, every single row uses the default image initially assigned to photo because the firebase call takes too long and the imgNode is already appended to the row before firebase finishes.  I'm not the most experienced javascript programmer, but how would you fix something like this so that the resource retrieved by updates into the row?  Would I need to use something like promises or async/await?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to change the order of your code a bit:

```
//Get the player
var player = collection[i];

//Create a new table row
var row = document.createElement("TR");
row.id = player.Id;

//Add the player profile pic
var imgNode = document.createElement("TD");
var img = document.createElement("IMG");
var photo = "https://usatftw.files.wordpress.com/2014/10/nfl_logo_new2.jpg?w=1000&h=750";
img.setAttribute("src", photo);
playerbase.orderByKey().equalTo(player.Id).on('child_added', (function(currentImage){
    return function(snap) {
       currentImage.setAttribute("src", snap.val());
    }
})(img));


img.setAttribute("width", "55px");
img.setAttribute("height", "55px");
imgNode.appendChild(img);
imgNode.className = "player-photo";
row.appendChild(imgNode);
```

Now let me try to explain what happens here. Instead of setting a variable in your callback function, which obviously doesn't work, you save a reference to each image object. When callback occurs, it has the correct object to operate on and change the state.

How the hell does that work?
In, your loop, you create a lot of images. Think of them as img1, img2, img3...imgN
Now for each image we have a callback function: cb1, cb2, cb3...cbN
But callbacks may not return in order. So it may be cb3, cb1, cb2...
What we do is create a new function. This function will bind img1 to cb1, img2 to cb2, etc.

Since Firebase API still expects to receive a function with one argument, we return it:

```
return function(snap) {
   currentImage.setAttribute("src", snap.val());
}
```

But now current image is always to correct image for the callback.

Comment: Wow this works beautifully.  Would you care to explain what exactly is currentImage in this case if it is different than photo?

Comment: That's quite complex, so I'll update my answer with the explanation.